# CPYTOPCD command in CLP copies the DB2 file (containing XML) successfully but file does not show in QDLS subfolders

Tags: ibm-midrange, control-language

I have a batch job which invokes CLP and uses CPYTOPCD command to copy a DB2 File which contains XML data. In CLP's job log, it says file is successfully copied but when I checked the QDLS subfolder...QDLS/XXXXXX/XXXXX/ERR/ , the file does not show up there. I tried both Iseries Navigator as well as thru command WRKFLR but all in vain. When I run the CPYTOPCD command manually, it does copy the file in folder. This is happening in Client's UAT box.

However when I run the batch job in our development's box, it copies the file successfully.

Not sure if is this a problem from Developer's end or Sys Admin's end?

Comment: maybe a slash is needed before qdls.  If you have a home directory set the slash is needed at the start of the path.  I would use cpytostmf.

Comment: Also, if at all possible, use something other than QDLS.

Comment: Last time i have similar problem - got data with null inside. CPYTOPCD is old stuffs. Got some limitations like cannot handle null. Try using CPYTOIMPF  (Copy to Import File)  and write to Root file system instead of QDLS.

Comment: QDLS is very likely inappropriate on a "client's" system. Too many assumptions are needed, and some are likely to contradict client restrictions. Use CPYTOSTMF for source or program-described PFs, or use CPYTOIMPF. In either case, use a modern file system; and avoid /QDLS.